# How to find whether SSDT-BT is installed or not?

Tags: sql, registry, bids, sql-server-data-tools

We are trying to determine whether SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) is installed on a machine via registry key.

When it was known as BIDS (up until SQL 2012), I was able to find via the registry key, but that key is not used by the new software.  Does anyone know where the right registry key can be found?

Comment: The new SSDT seems to be a mess, version-wise.  I installed the Visual Studio 2017 version today, and I get four different version numbers.  15.6.4 and 15.1.61801.210 (from Visual Studio Help/About), 14.0.16156.0 and 15.6.27428.2015 (from Programs and Features).  So, I have no idea what version it is either, nor which one I should be looking for in the registry.  The download website says it's 15.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an SSDT registry directory under:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SSDT

Comment: I did not find this key for SSDT using Visual Studio 2017.